# How to retrive column length from %type variable in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way to retrieve the actual column size from a %type variable without using a select statement? For example consider the following program:

```
declare

l_emp_salary  employees.emp_salary%type;
l_max_length varchar2(500);

begin

select emp_id into l_emp_salary
    from employees
where emp_id = '123';


-- l_max_length := length(l_emp_salary); Something like that

end;
```

I do not want to use a query that retrieve the column size from the `dba_tab_columns` or a query like the following:

```
select 
   max(vsize(emp_salary)) into l_max_length
from employees;
```

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: You can check the column length using data dictionary tables. In PLSQL you will have to use hit and trial method to do it. I mean keep increasing the vaule of the colum till it gives error .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the maximum possible length of a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696583/is-it-possible-to-get-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-variable)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Using a select statement seems to be the best approach.