# PLSQL dynamically truncate string to varchar2 column size

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm looking for a way to dynamically truncate a string to the max size of a varchar2 column.

See example below.

Table definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_table
( 
  log varchar2(50)
);
```

Code

```sql
DECLARE
  v_str some_table.log%TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_str := SUBSTR('a text longer than 50 chars ...', 1,  50 /*HOW TO GET 50 DYNAMICALLY HERE ?*/ );
END;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696583/is-it-possible-to-get-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-variable?

Comment: If your intent is only to write code that inserts a log record  and you expect most strings to fit, then I would recommend executing the "max col size" code only if an exception is raised. The cost of the query might be so significant that you can save considerable time and resources if you perform that operation only when required. Of course, if it's always longer than the maximum then it would be wasteful to let an exception be raised.

Comment: Thanks for your advices Jeff Holt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select char_length 
  from user_tab_columns 
 where table_name = 'SOME_TABLE' 
   and column_name = 'LOG';
```

would return a value of 50 (the length of the `log` column in the `some_table` table)

Comment: Thanks, indeed this can do the job.
The only bad point here is that the code will always be evaluated at runtime whereas the column size is a static information...

Comment: @Kino101 - You could use the query to set a package variable which would cache the result for subsequent calls.   In which case you'd only be calling it once a session.  Of course, the cache wouldn't get updated if the underlying column's length was changed but I'd assume that wouldn't be a huge issue.

Comment: Another way to avoid this query at runtime is wrapping it in a function that sets `result_cache relies_on(user_tab_columns)` to cache the return value for each table/column (and dump the cache whenever user_tab_columns changes).

Comment: @EdmCoff - I'm reasonably sure that back before Oracle deprecated the `relies_on` clause in 12g that there were restrictions that prevented the result cache from working with data dictionary tables.  I'm not seeing those restrictions in the more recent documentation so I'm guessing those restrictions are no longer there.

Comment: You want `CHAR_LENGTH` not `DATA_LENGTH`. And yes, storing the column length in a package variable is exactly what I have done when writing log entries and didn't want the log table column length as a magic number in my code. So this would be my recommendation, too.

Comment: @JustinCave I was not aware that was deprecated. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Getting (and caching) the column length is probably the way to go, but just for fun and riffing from an approach [in this discussion](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/627335/getting-size-of-variable):

```
DECLARE
  v_str some_table.log%TYPE;
  v_ret pls_integer;
  v_len pls_integer;
BEGIN
  v_ret := anydata.convertchar('-').getchar(v_str);
  v_len := length(v_str);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_len);

  v_str := substr('a text longer than 50 chars, a text longer than 50 chars, a text longer than 50 chars...', 1,  v_len);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
END;
/

dbms_output:
50
a text longer than 50 chars, a text longer than 50
```

Because it's using `convertchar` and `getchar` rather than the `varchar2` versions, the result is the literal char `-` padded to its maximum length based on the variable's data type.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9408f316481f2e40d37d1fc71923cefd)

You can read more about `anydata` [at Oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/anydata) or [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/ANYDATA-TYPE.html).

You could still cache that, or work it out on exception. If you were going to do this often and performance was acceptable without caching/catching, you could possibly wrap it in a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE trunc_string(p_str out varchar2, p_val varchar2)
AS
  v_ret pls_integer;
  v_len pls_integer;
BEGIN
  v_ret := anydata.convertchar('-').getchar(p_str);
  v_len := length(p_str);
  p_str := substr(p_val, 1,  v_len);
END;
/
```

and then call that as:

```
DECLARE
  v_str1 some_table.log%TYPE;
  v_str2 varchar2(30);
BEGIN
  trunc_string(v_str1, 'a text longer than 50 chars, a text longer than 50 chars, a text longer than 50 chars...');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_str1);

  trunc_string(v_str2, 'a text longer than 30 chars, a text longer than 30 chars, a text longer than 30 chars...');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_str2);
END;
/

dbms_output:
a text longer than 50 chars, a text longer than 50
a text longer than 30 chars, a
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65270aabebea2dfa5351e3c187c3b4bc)

But that's probably overkill... though that could be said about using `anydata` at all.